# why my app based on boost::asio didn't accept new connection

Tags: c++, boost

I write a test app which creates 2,000 connections to my tcp server. After kill/start my test app a few times, my tcp server cannot accept new connection anymore? I have no idea of debugging this problem, any suggestion? Some code snippet lists below:

```
 Server(io_service& s, tcp::endpoint const& listen_endpoint, size_t thread_number):io_(s),
signals_(s),
acceptor_(io_, listen_endpoint),
thread_pool_size_(thread_number) {
  signals_.add(SIGINT);
  signals_.add(SIGTERM);
  signals_.async_wait(bind(&Server::Stop, this));
  shared_ptr<ClientType> c(new ClientType(io_));

  acceptor_.async_accept(c->socket, bind(&Server::AfterAccept, this, c, _1));

  //launch thread to preapre message
  MessageThread d;
  MyApp& app = AppHolder::Instance();
  d.support_text_message = app.config().support_text_message;
  d.support_digit_message = app.config().support_digit_message;
  d.interval = app.config().interval;
  boost::thread thrd1(d);
}

  void AfterAccept(shared_ptr<ClientType>& c, error_code const& ec) {
    // Check whether the server was stopped by a signal before this completion
    // handler had a chance to run.
    if (!acceptor_.is_open()) {
      BOOSTER_INFO("Server") << "thread id: " << this_thread::get_id() << " acceptor is closed";
      return;
    }

    if (!ec) {
      c->StartJob();
      shared_ptr<ClientType> c2(new ClientType(io_));
      acceptor_.async_accept(c2->socket, bind(&Server::AfterAccept, this, c2, _1));
    }
  }
```

Comment: what does netstat show?

Comment: @Nik I run netstat -ap command, many CLOSE_WAIT status.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before the call to `acceptor_.async_accept` try adding the line:

```
acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
```

Comment: Also thanks to @Nik, when using resue_address(true), the CLOSE_WIAT stutu is gone, and I cannot reproduce this problem now. :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me server side:

```
void Util::Clearup(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket* socket, boost::asio::io_service& 
IO_service, tcp::acceptor* acceptor)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send, error);
    socket->close();
    if (error)
    {
        std::cout << "Clearup failed: " << error.message() << std::endl;
    }

    IO_service.stop();
    IO_service.restart();
    acceptor->close();

    std::cout << "Util:Clearup(..)" << std::endl;
}
```