# Why causes many CLOSE_WAIT in boost asio app?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I posted one question a few days ago, 
[why my app based on boost::asio didn't accept new connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300926/why-my-app-based-on-boostasio-didnt-accept-new-connection)
And I thought it was solved.

But it is not, today I can reproduce the error sometimes. After stopping/starting the 2000 client apps which connect to my TCP server. In some cases, many connections are shown as CLOSE_WAIT.

I close the connection manually using below code:

```
  void CloseSocket() {
    try {
      socket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
      socket.close();
      BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "close the connection";
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
      BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << "thread id: " << this_thread::get_id() << " " << e.what();
    }
  }
```

Also set address to be reused

```
  acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
```

Some people said it's not recommended that closing the socket manually, let asio do it for you. But some people said you should call shutdown before close the socket. I use the latter way, but the problem still exists.

Comment: Use non-throwing overload of [shutdown](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/shutdown/overload2.html) to be sure that you always reach the next line. Make sure all the paths in your code eventually lead to the socket closing.

Comment: I changed code, thank you.

Comment: Get rid of the shutdown. It happens anyway as part of the close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I resolved this problem because I add this command before lauching the server

> ulimit -n 10240

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

When a TCP connection is being closed:

- The initiating side enters an active close.  This will place the initiator's connection into a `TIME_WAIT` state, preventing the address from being reused as a means to guarantee late packets are not received as part of a new connection.  The [`socket_base::reuse_address`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/reuse_address.html) option allows for the address to be reused, even if the connection is in a `TIME_WAIT` state.  This is often used to allow a server to restart and immediately begin listening to the same port.
- The receiving side enters a passive close.  The receiver's connection will remain in a `CLOSE_WAIT` state until the socket has been closed.  When the socket is closed, it allowing the address to be released back and reused by the kernel.

As [Igor R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20370086/why-causes-many-close-wait-in-boost-asio-app#comment30411998_20370086)'s succinctly suggest, the problem can be resolved by verifying that all paths allow for the socket to close.  Based on [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20300926/1053968), given `ClientType` aggregates socket, and `ClientType` instances are managed by `shared_ptr`, it may be possible that `ClientType` instances are never being deleted, as the socket will close during its destruction.

Also, while `socket_base::reuse_address` will not affect `CLOSE_WAIT`, it may still be a good idea to use for the server's acceptor.

Comment: Does resue_address option have any side effect? The resused connection will receive the late packets or not?

Comment: As far as I understand, "automatic close" in the Asio context usually means automatic management of session/socket objects' lifespan. This is really the preferred design in many cases.

Comment: @DeanChen For a Boost.Asio acceptor (socket in a listening state), it should have no noticeable side effects.  For other cases, while a previous connection's packets can be received as if they are part of the current connection, it is not likely.  It requires a lingering packet to be received after the same client starts a new connection with the same address, same remote port, and the lingering packet's sequence number matches the negotiated sequence number expected on the new connection.

Comment: @IgorR. Thanks for the correction.  I forgot that the socket gets closed when its service implementation is destroyed.  Definitely the preferred design.